# Using Type.Equality with PolyKinds

Tags: haskell, ghc, higher-kinded-types

This compiling code is a minimized example of [this code](https://gist.github.com/emilaxelsson/ed5ffd25f11e56e6ccfc) from an answer to [this issue](https://github.com/emilaxelsson/syntactic/issues/8) with syntactic-2.0. I'm also using a definition of `sameModType` derived from [`sameNat`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.0/docs/src/GHC-TypeLits.html#line-193) in Data.Type.Equality.

I had been using this solution without issue, but I'd like to make the modulus `q` be kind-polymorphic, with the specific goal of making `Proxy (nat :: Nat)` to just `nat :: Nat` (while still being able to use moduli of kind `*`).

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs, 
             MultiParamTypeClasses, 
             FunctionalDependencies, 
             FlexibleContexts, 
             FlexibleInstances,
             TypeOperators, 
             ScopedTypeVariables,
             DataKinds,
             KindSignatures #-}

import Data.Tagged
import Data.Proxy
import Data.Type.Equality
import Data.Constraint
import Unsafe.Coerce
import GHC.TypeLits

newtype Zq q i = Zq i

data ZqType q
  where
    ZqType :: (Modulus q Int) => Proxy q -> ZqType (Zq q Int)

class (Integral i) => Modulus a i | a -> i where
    value :: Tagged a i

instance (KnownNat q) => Modulus (Proxy (q :: Nat)) Int where 
    value = Tagged $ fromIntegral $ natVal (Proxy :: Proxy q)

sameModType :: (Modulus p i, Modulus q i) 
            => Proxy p -> Proxy q -> Maybe (p :~: q)
sameModType p q | (proxy value p) == (proxy value q) = 
                     Just $ unsafeCoerce Refl
                | otherwise = Nothing

typeEqSym :: ZqType p -> ZqType q -> Maybe (Dict (p ~ q))
typeEqSym (ZqType p) (ZqType q) = do
        Refl <- sameModType p q  -- LINE 39
        return Dict              -- LINE 40
```

But when I add the `-XPolyKinds` extension to the code above, I get several compile errors:

```
Foo.hs:39:36:
    Could not deduce (k1 ~ k)
    ...
    Expected type: Proxy q0
      Actual type: Proxy q2
    Relevant bindings include
      q :: Proxy q2 (bound at Foo.hs:38:30)
      p :: Proxy q1 (bound at Foo.hs:38:19)
    In the second argument of ‘sameFactoredType’, namely ‘q’
    In a stmt of a 'do' block: Refl <- sameFactoredType p q

Foo.hs:40:16:
    Could not deduce (k ~ k1)
    ...
    Relevant bindings include
      q :: Proxy q2 (bound at Foo.hs:38:30)
      p :: Proxy q1 (bound at Foo.hs:38:19)
    In the first argument of ‘return’, namely ‘Dict’
    In a stmt of a 'do' block: return Dict
    In the expression:
      do { Refl <- sameFactoredType p q;
           return Dict }

Foo.hs:40:16:
    Could not deduce (q1 ~ q2)
    ...
    Relevant bindings include
      q :: Proxy q2 (bound at Foo.hs:38:30)
      p :: Proxy q1 (bound at Foo.hs:38:19)
    In the first argument of ‘return’, namely ‘Dict’
    In a stmt of a 'do' block: return Dict
    In the expression:
      do { Refl <- sameFactoredType p q;
           return Dict }
```

I don't know enough about the magic going on in the type equality to know how to fix this. It appears that most of the kinds in question are hopelessly out of scope in terms of being able to enforce the constraints GHC is asking for, but I've never had this sort of problem before with `PolyKinds`. What needs to change to make the code compile with `PolyKinds`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if this is what you're looking for, but you can simply expose the kind of the underlying argument for later use:

```
data ZqType q k where
  ZqType :: Modulus q Int => Proxy (q :: k) -> ZqType (Zq q Int) ('KProxy :: KProxy k)

typeEqSym :: ZqType p k -> ZqType q k -> Maybe (Dict (p ~ q))
typeEqSym (ZqType p) (ZqType q) = do
        Refl <- sameModType p q  
        return Dict              

instance Modulus Int Int where 
instance Modulus (n :: Nat) Int where
```

`KProxy` should be in `Data.Proxy`, but it is just `data KProxy (x :: *) = KProxy`.

Contrived example:

```
>let x = ZqType (Proxy :: Proxy (10 :: Nat))
>let y = ZqType (Proxy :: Proxy Int)
>typeEqSym x y
<interactive>:25:13:
    Couldn't match kind `*' with `Nat'
    Expected type: ZqType (Zq Int Int) 'KProxy
      Actual type: ZqType (Zq Int Int) 'KProxy
    In the second argument of `typeEqSym', namely `y'
    In the expression: typeEqSym x y
```

Answer (score 5):

I can explain the problem, but as I'm not completely sure what you want to do, I'm not sure how you can best fix it.

The problem is in the definition of `ZqType`:

```
data ZqType q
  where
    ZqType :: (Modulus q Int) => Proxy q -> ZqType (Zq q Int)
```

It's somewhat misleading that the type parameter of `ZqType` is called `q`. This is a GADT, and the type parameters have nothing to do with the type parameters appearing in the constructors. I prefer giving a kind signature instead. What is the kind of `ZqType`? Well, `Zq q Int` is a datatype, so it has kind `*`. You're applying `ZqType` to `Zq q Int`, so the kind of `ZqType` is `* -> *` (despite `PolyKind`s). So we have

```
data ZqType :: * -> * where
  ZqType :: (Modulus q Int) => Proxy q -> ZqType (Zq q Int)
```

Next, let's see what's the type of the `ZqType` constructor? Without poly kinds, it's what you wrote down:

```
ZqType :: (Modulus q Int) => Proxy q -> ZqType (Zq q Int)
```

But with `PolyKind`s, `q` is appearing only in kind-polymorphic positions, so this becomes:

```
ZqType :: forall (q :: k). (Modulus q Int) => Proxy q -> ZqType (Zq q Int)
```

Now let's look at how you use this in `sameModType`:

```
typeEqSym :: ZqType a -> ZqType b -> Maybe (Dict (a ~ b))
typeEqSym (ZqType p) (ZqType q) = do
  ...
```

I've renamed type variables to avoid confusion. So `a` is an unknown type of kind `*`, and `b` is another unknown type of kind `*`. You're pattern matching on the GADT. At this time, GHC learns that `a` is actually `Zq q1 Int` for some unknown `q1` of some unknown kind `k1`. Furthermore, GHC learns that `b` is actually `Zq q2 Int` for some unknown `q2` of some unknown kind `k2`. In particular, we have no idea here that `k1` and `k2` are the same, because this is nowhere enforced.

You then go on calling `sameModType` which expects both proxies to be of the same kind, resulting in the first of your kind errors. The remaining errors are all a consequence of the same problem.

Comment: A great explanation, thanks! Perhaps someone else will know what to do.

Comment: The reason I don't know what to do is because this is a small example that lacks motivation (similarly the other example you linked to). I'd need to know why you define `ZqType` the way you define it, and also why you believe you need kind polymorphism here in the first place, before I could try to give advice on how to make it work.

Comment: The developer of the library proposed that definition for `ZqType` as a solution for using my `Zq` type with the library (i.e. a type with an infinite possibilities for a phantom parameter). I think `ZqType` could change, my understanding is that it needs to have kind `*->*`. The function `typeEqSym` is from a class in the library itself, so its type is fixed (but definition can change).

Comment: I'd like kind-polymorphism so that the kind of the modulus is not restricted to a single type/kind. It should be up to the end user to pick a `Modulus` implementation. Previously, I had been testing with an implementation with kind `*`, now I'm interested in using `TypeLits`, with kind `Nat`, and it seems crazy to have to wrap it in a `Proxy`.